# Python 3.3 - subprocess.call and the GIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, gil

Simple question:

Would a python instance I created using subprocces.call be subject to the same GIL as the parent process?

Comment: I'm never going to understand while people downvote perfectly legitimate questions...

Answer (score 3):

Subprocess does not share the same GIL. But [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) does wait the subuprocess to be terminated.

Comment: Could I use multiprocessing to prevent the call from hanging my program?

Comment: @jtsmith1287, Use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) unless you want wait the subprocess.